# SQL - Finding box within box

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE boxes (
    box_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    x1 INTEGER,
    x2 INTEGER,
    y1 INTEGER,
    y2 INTEGER
)
```

How would I query to select all boxes that are completely inside another box in the table? Here is what I tried, but I am not getting the right answer:

```
SELECT b2.box_id FROM boxes AS b1, boxes AS b2
WHERE (
    b2.x1 >= b1.x1 AND
    b2.x2 <= b1.x2 AND
    b2.y1 >= b1.y1 AND
    b2.y2 <= b1.y2
);
```

Thank you so much in advance to anyone who can push me in the right direction! Cheers!

Comment: FYI this is a line not a box

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: also a full [mre] would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "completely within".  If you mean that they cannot share borders, then use inequalities

```
SELECT b2.box_id
FROM boxes b1 JOIN
     boxes b2
     ON b2.x1 > b1.x1 AND
        b2.x2 < b1.x2 AND
        b2.y1 > b1.y1 AND
        b2.y2 < b1.y2;
```

If you mean they can share borders but are not coincident, then:

```
SELECT b2.box_id
FROM boxes b1 JOIN
     boxes b2
     ON b2.x1 >= b1.x1 AND
        b2.x2 <= b1.x2 AND
        b2.y1 >= b1.y1 AND
        b2.y2 <= b1.y2 AND
        NOT (b2.x1 = b1.x1 AND
             b2.x2 = b1.x2 AND
             b2.y1 = b1.y1 AND
             b2.y2 = b1.y2
            );
```